# Adding N elements from user to an vector endline

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, addition

I'm getting trouble using an vector for add elements on the end of line.

My struct:

```
struct process_s {
       int type_id;
       int line_id;
       int product_id;
       };
```

Then I convert it to an vector using:

```
std::vector<process_s> process_v;
```

My next step is populate two lines:

```
       process_v.at(1).type_id = 1;
       process_v.at(1).line_id = 1;
       process_v.at(1).product_id = 2;
```

And

```
       process_v.at(2).type_id = 1;
       process_v.at(2).line_id = 2;
       process_v.at(2).product_id = 2;
```

From now, my goal is get all user input and add on the end from first(1) or second line(2).
Oncetime all data is get, I will duplicate it using ODD and EVEN, or in other words, i will copy line one(1) to line three (3) and samething copying line two(2) for line (4), the number of lines is unknow also.

The first problem is trying add more data from the user input on the end from first or second line, was trying using this:

```
process.at(1) = 1
```

Or

```
process(1).push_back = 1
```

From this point I need store all user input on the respective line, once time the user finish the input, write an TXT like this:

The specification is for this type (type_id) and need be on line (line_id), the first product need be (product_id), the second (product_id), etc...

None of those are working, someone would point me what I'm missing please?

Thanks in advice

Comment: for example there is no `.at(1)` in your vector. The vector is just empty. At first you need to `push_back` the elements. (Also you are not converting to an vector you are initializing a vector). Ah and also it is maybe a good idea to change the title, to get more views, it is a little bit confusing. And please explain what you mean with `line`.(maybe you mean a "line" (like for example at(0)) in the vector this is usually refered as position.

Comment: Line is how the products will need be stored, so one line with some products, another line with other products. The goal is make an TXT explaining step by step how store products, the number of products is unknow, like the lines, this will be determined by product specification in another fuction, from now my problem is how to have this array / vector with all data to makre the reports and check if the logic is valid.

Comment: please don't use the word line if you refer to an element of a vector

Answer (score 2):

By default, when you create a vector it is empty so you cannot refer to the "first" or "second" element in the vector.

If you know your vector should have 2 elements you can initialize it with a size of 2:

```
std::vector<process_s> process_v(2);
```

Then you can populate it:

```
   process_v.at(0).type_id = 1;
   process_v.at(0).line_id = 1;
   process_v.at(0).product_id = 2;

   process_v.at(1).type_id = 1;
   process_v.at(1).line_id = 2;
   process_v.at(1).product_id = 2;
```

Note that vectors are zero-based in C++ so you need to refer to the first line as `process_v.at(0)` (or `process_v[0]`)

If you don't know how big your vector should be you should use `push_back` to add `process_s` to your vector:

```
std::vector<process_s> process_v;

process_s p;
p.type_id = 1;
p.line_id = 1;
p.product_id = 2;

process_v.push_back(p);
```

Or

```
process_v.push_back(process_s{1,1,2});
```

Or

```
process_v.push_back({1,1,2});
```

Comment: With an delimited vector from the first part I see how set the line with process_v.at(0) to first line or process_v.at(1) to second line... But and about the second example? The process_v.push_back({1,1,2}) doesnt have an reference about witch line will be added... I'm confusing too abou how keep increasing it, for example:
process_v.push_back({1,1,2})
And if the user insert more 3 itens like: 10, 90, 1118?
I need read the entire line of vector and remake the string for:
process_v.push_back({1,1,2, 10, 90, 1118})
Or
process_v.push_back({10})
process_v.push_back({20})
process_v.push_back({118})

Comment: [push_back](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/push_back/) adds a new element to the end of the vector. So, if it empty originally, after calling `push_back` it will have a size of 1. `push_back` will take a copy of the value passed to it. I've added an example that calls `push_back` more explicitly, hopefully that makes it more clear. `push_back({1,1,2})` is just short-cut.

Comment: The first example compile without errors: std::vector<process_s> process_v;

process_s p;
p.type_id = 1;
p.line_id = 1;
p.product_id = 2;

process_v.push_back(p);

The other two give some errors. By the way, when the program is runing and try insert data i get this message: "This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way. Please contact the application's support team for more information."
I'm using Windows 7 x64 and compiling with Dev-C++ 4.9.9.2

Comment: The other two are C++11 only. [Live demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/2y4Plzi8QjGbYS2e). I can't help you with your other error though, I'm afraid. Try to create a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) and post a separate question.